# App with firebase authentication keeps stopping

Tags: firebase-authentication

I have three activities. Login,Create Account activity and PostAccountActivity in my app. When Click Create account button I get a crash with the following output on the logcat window

> 2021-02-03 11:31:47.430 4954-4989/com.example.fauth E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: grpc-default-executor-0
> Process: com.example.fauth, PID: 4954
> java.lang.AssertionError
> at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.getResourceResolver(DnsNameResolver.java:536)
> at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.access$500(DnsNameResolver.java:60)
> at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$1.run(DnsNameResolver.java:211)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Comment: did you solved it ?

Comment: Yeah i did. Thanks

Comment: How did you solve it @edwin? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Firebase console > cloud firestore >rules.....Edit the rules to adjust to a future date

Answer (score 0):

Go to Firebase console > click your project > cloud firestore > rules.....Edit the timestamp date to a date that you want, probably a future date. Because for me the timestamp date had already passed so I had to adjust to a more future date. Dont forget to change the version of your rules too.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone with your database reference to view, edit,
    // and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
    // your rules
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 12, 30);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).